# How to Number Rows Every 1000

Tags: excel, google-sheets

How can I autonumber for every 1000 rows? without using macros.

I am trying to divide/batch 100k records for every 1000. And i figured creating batches and autonumbering them is a start.

Row1

```
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
1   6
1   7
1   8
2   1
2   2
2   3
2   4
2   5
2   6
2   7
2   8
3   1
3   2
3   3
3   4
3   5
3   6
3   7
3   8
```

Comment: Number them how, sequentially from 1-1000?  Or, you want every thousandth row to be denoted?

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** enter:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROW()/8,0)
```

and copy down.  In **B1** enter:

```
=MOD(ROW()-1,8)+1
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You type the first and second rows as 1 and 2 and then highlighting them and dragging from the little square at the bottom right of the selection will autofill with sequential numbers (ie 1, 2, 3, 4). Once you get to 1000 you can copy and paste the whole column up to that point at the bottom. Pasting 99 times should provide you with what you are requesting. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
MOD(dividend, divisor)
```

https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Use that function with 1000 as the divisor.  That should work